# c# regular expression exclude certain character

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match a string in C# using Regex.IsMatch that has the following format:

> ([anything here[anything here]anything here])+

Example: `[mark[MARK]mark][[spacing]]` would be a valid string, but `[[[spacing]spacing]` would be an invalid one.

Notice that

> "anything here"

string cannot contain

> "[" or "]"

, and it also can be empty.

I tried something like`@"(\[{1}\w*\[{1}\w*\]{1}\w*\]{1})+"`, but I don't know how to tell the Regex engine that `\w*` cannot contain

> "[" or "]"

.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [balancing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html), enclose the whole expression within a non-capturing group, and quantify the group with `+` (one or more occurrences):

```
^(?:\[(?>[^][]+|(?<o>)\[|(?<-o>)])*(?(o)(?!))])+$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3A%5C%5B%28%3F%3E%5B%5E%5D%5B%5Cn%5D%2B%7C%28%3F%3Co%3E%29%5C%5B%7C%28%3F%3C-o%3E%29%5D%29*%28%3F%28o%29%28%3F!%29%29%5D%29%2B%5Cr%3F%24&i=%5Bmark%5BMARK%5Dmark%5D%5B%5Bspacing%5D%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%5B%5B%5Bspacing%5Dspacing%5D&o=m)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:`   - start of a non-capturing `+`-quantified group

  - `\[`  - a `[`
  - `(?>[^][]+|(?<o>)\[|(?<-o>)])*` - search for any 1+ chars other than `[` and `]` or `[` (adding it to Group "o" stack) or  `]` (removing it off the Group "o" stack)
  - `(?(o)(?!))` - if group "o" is not empty, fail the match, look for the next paired `[...]`
  - `]`
- `)+` - one or more occurrences of the inner pattern
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: FYI, in the demo, I added `\r?` at the end and `\n` into the `[^][]` class since the demo input is a multiline string. You do not need them in the actual pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex

```
^(\[[^\[\]]*\[[^\[\]]*\][^\[\]]*\])+$
```

Regex explanations:

- `^` Match starts of the string
- `(` Start a group
- `\[` Match starting `[`
- `[^\[\]]*` Match zero or more string that is **not** `[` and is **not** `]`
- `\[` Match `[` again
- `[^\[\]]*` Match zero or more string that is **not** `[` and is **not** `]`
- `\]` Match closing `]`
- `[^\[\]]*` Match zero or more string that is **not** `[` and is **not** `]` (again)
- `\]` Match last `]`
- `)` Ending group
- `+` Quantifier to matches previous group one or more occurence
- `$` Match ends of the string